# knex.js + pg specify varchar to be > 255

Tags: string, postgresql, knex.js, varchar, postgresql-9.4

When creating a table in knex migrations, I have indicated a col as such:

`table.string("content");`

It defaults to varchar 255. I would like it to be able to hold more text. How do I indicate to knex that I want this to occur?

Comment: I never used `knex`, but would guess that `table.text("content")` could do the trick, just purely on logic and postgresql data types. I may be wrong :)

Comment: Issue is you basically have to use a `.raw()` and write the PG SQL yourself. It appears Knex does not support it explicitly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can define the col in following way to set the length of the string:

```
    table.string("content", 1000)
```

This results to:

```
    content         character varying(1000)
```

Reference:
http://knexjs.org/#Schema-string

Comment: OP is correct that there is no performance difference between text and nvarchar: "There is no performance difference among these three types."  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: table.text("content") can be used for Postgres. See https://knexjs.org/ by screen-search "table.text"

Answer (score 2):

There is also other way to do it:

```
table.text(columnName, [textType]);
```

Adds a text column, with optional textType for MySql text datatype preference where **textType defaults to text**.

PSQL text type description: variable **unlimited** length.

References:
http://knexjs.org/#Schema-text
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-character.html
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/